# Instantiation of class in controller action not mapping post data for array of ints

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, .net-6.0

Using EF Core, C# .net 6 generic API setup, client is SPA.

I'm trying to instantiate some post data into a strongly-typed object:

```
public IActionResult Submit(MyModel model)
```

What the client sends:

```
gameIds: [9, 8, 7, 18, 17, 6, 5, 14, 12]
```

What the server gets (inspecting generic received object):

```
{[gameIds, {[9,8,7,18,17,6,5,14,12]}]}
```

In the populated model:

```
GameIds Count = 0   System.Collections.Generic.List<int>
```

All of my other properties automatically map correctly: ints, strings, etc.

I have a bit of an odd setup (to me anyhow) trying to get a list of Ids from a many-many foreign entity relationship when available, or just storing a `List<int>` for use in the service saving this off when it's a new record.

The model class itself:

```
private List<int> _gameIds;
[NotMapped]
public List<int> GameIds { 
    get { return (_gameIds?.Count == 0 ? Games?.Select(x => x.Id)?.ToList() : _gameIds) ?? new List<int>(); }
    set { _gameIds = value; }
}
public List<GameModel> Games { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure if my GameIds declaration is messing things up, or if it's something I'm missing in the instantiation, or if my approach is just wrong in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you review in details your get part of property, written in a less compact form:

```
List<int> list = null;

if (_gameIds != null && _gameIds.Count == 0)
   list = Games?.Select(x => x.Id)?.ToList();
else
   list = _gameIds;

return list ?? new List<int>();
```

In case in which _gameIds == null, you return the else part, that is null, and return a new empty list. I prefer don't compact a lot because is more readable:

```
   get
   {
      var list = _gameIds != null && _gameIds.Count == 0 ? 
         Games?.Select(x => x.Id)?.ToList() : 
         _gameIds;

      return list ?? new List<int>();
   }
```